# Counting all association objects and updating a counter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 models:

```
class Products < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchases

class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Product
```

The products model has a column `purchase_count`

I want a very fast efficient way to update this counter that basically runs this sql:

```
UPDATE products SET purchase_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) from purchases where active=1 and product_id = 123) where id = 123
```

Can I do this with ActiveRecord ?  If not, how can I do this with just raw sql?

Comment: you say your `product` model has a `purchase_count` but in your query, you update `purchases` table.

Comment: @ArunKumar sorry, fixed that type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use a `counter_cache` column to make it efficient. Rails allows you to set a `counter_cache` option to `true` in the `belongs_to` model(`purchase`). But you should generate a migration to add a column to `products` table.

For more, look for `counter_cache` in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference

If you just don't want to count all the associated objects and instead need a condition to be passed in, you need a *custom* `counter cache`. Have a look at http://douglasfshearer.com/2006/10/06/custom-counter-cache-with-conditions.html for an example.

Comment: But I need to add a WHERE clause, it isn't just counting all records.  Also, what query does the counter cache do, is it a COUNT or a increment/decrement?

Comment: @Blankman, Ah, you need a `custom counter cache`. See http://douglasfshearer.com/2006/10/06/custom-counter-cache-with-conditions.html